# Angular ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError on Input. OpenLayers Map

Tags: angular, openlayers

My MapComponent uses ControlButtonsComponent in the html and binds the Map from openlayers with @Input into the ControlButtons. This gives me the error:

```
core.js:5980 ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'undefined'. Current value: '[object Object]'.
at throwErrorIfNoChangesMode (core.js:6549)
at bindingUpdated (core.js:12660)
at Module.ɵɵproperty (core.js:14475)
at MapComponent_Template (map.component.html:2)
at executeTemplate (core.js:9323)
at refreshView (core.js:9192)
at refreshComponent (core.js:10358)
at refreshChildComponents (core.js:8989)
at refreshView (core.js:9242)
at refreshComponent (core.js:10358)
```

even thought I have a ngIf="Map" in the selector

this is the html in MapComponent:

```
<app-control-buttons *ngIf="Map" [Map]="Map"></app-control-buttons>
```

an important element in this is probably how Map gets initialized in the MapComponent (taken from https://medium.com/runic-software/a-simple-guide-to-openlayers-in-angular-b10f6feb3df1):

```
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        if (!this.Map) {
            this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => this.initMap());
        }
        setTimeout(() => this.mapReady.emit(this.Map));
    }
```

this is the ControlButtonsComponent:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Map} from 'ol';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-control-buttons',
    templateUrl: './control-buttons.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./control-buttons.component.less'],
})
export class ControlButtonsComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() Map!: Map;
    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Comment: Try [hidden]="!Map" instead of *ngIf="Map". However, you are doing something and that change is unknown from angular.

Comment: @DevangPatel did not work.. says "Previous value for 'hidden': 'true'. Current value: 'false'" with the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ahh I've found a solution:

change the previous ngAfterViewInit() to this (i didnt really use the emit for anything). I created a mapReady variable that gets set true when map is ready:

```
    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    if (!this.Map) {
        this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => this.initMap());
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.mapReady = true
    });
}
```

and check for mapReady variable in the html:

```
<app-control-buttons *ngIf="mapReady" [Map]="Map"></app-control-buttons>
```